# How to run for loop in batch file step by step

Tags: matlab, for-loop, batch-file

I am trying to call MATLAB from the batch file several times. In this way, I used for loop to execute my MATLAB scripts several times. But what I got after running my batch file is to run all MATLAB files simultaneously. What I want is that, firstly, it runs once MATLAB, and when it is finished, it starts to run for the next time. Here is my code. Any help will be appreciated!

```
@echo off
for /l %%x in (1, 1, 2) do  matlab -r "cd('H:\EngFiles\Ali\Backups codes\New set with multiple scenarios_Parallel');Bi_Objective_algorithm; exit"

pause
```

Answer (score 4):

This page in the documentation describes how to call MATLAB from a Windows batch script: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlabwindows.html

The `-wait` option tells the `matlab` command to not return until MATLAB exits. For example:

```
matlab -wait -r "disp(1); exit"
```

However, since R2019a the `-r` switch is no longer recommended. That is the release where they introduced the much better `-batch` option:

```
matlab -batch "disp(1)"
```

Note that it is no longer necessary to include `exit` in the command.